# Prove that if $|X|=\aleph _0$ then there exist a family of sets, $\mathcal{F}$, of subsets of $X$, s.t $|\mathcal{F}|=\aleph$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $X$ be a set such that $|X|=\aleph _0$. I need to find a family of sets $\mathcal{F}$, of subsets of $X$ such that $|\mathcal{F}|=|\mathbb{R}|$.

I saw a couple of examples of Specific X but I can't construct a family of sets which hold the condition for a general set X with $|X|=\aleph _0$.

**edit**: I forgot to mention an important condition that $\mathcal{F}$ must hold:
for every $A,B\in \mathcal{F}$ the intersection $A\cap B$ is finite.

Comment: Do you know what are the cardinalities of $\Bbb R$ and $\mathcal P(X)$? Or is there some additional requirement on $\cal F$ that you forgot to mention?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila In my course we denote the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ by $\aleph$ and if $|X|=\aleph _0$ then I know that $|\mathcal{P}(X)|=|\mathbb{R}|=\aleph$, and the only condintion on $\mathcal{F}$ is that it is a family of sets of subsets of $X$

Comment: Is $\mathcal P(X)$ not a sufficient answer, then?

Comment: @AsafKaragila only now I realized I forgot to mention the extra important condition that $\mathcal{F}$ must hold. I edited the question. sorry :(